# Add Swift code snippet in Xcode 6

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I want to add the following code to Xcode's user code snippets:

```
println(" = \()")
```

I drag it to the code snippets area, I give it a **Title**, a **Summary**, a **Completion shortcut**, and a **Completion scope** of `All`

[image]

Why doesn't it show up in Xcode's auto-complete suggestions?
I am using Xcode 6.0.1 (6A317)

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you have a conflicting completion shortcut with one that already exists in XODE: "println".  You need to choose something unique. There are some good explanations of the dos and don'ts here:

http://nshipster.com/xcode-snippets/